# Argo Workflow errors out with Exit Code 145

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argo-workflows, argo

I am trying to run an Argo Workflow. But it gives me this error message:

> Error (exit code 145)

My .Net Core 5.0 application is trying to receive a `urlPath` as parameter and then processes the text input within that file and return it. Below is my `YAML` file for reference purposes.

```
metadata:
  generatename: read-data-
  namespace: argo
spec:
  entrypoint: read-data
  templates:
    - name: read-data
      dag:
        tasks:
          - name: read-all-data
            template: read-all-data
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: fileUrl
                  value: 'https://dpaste.com/24593EK38'
    - name: read-all-data
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: fileUrl
      container:
        image: 'manankapoor2705/cli_readdata:latest'
        command:
          - dotnet
          - /app/bin/Debug/net5.0/cli_readdata.dll
        args:
          - '--fileUrl={{inputs.parameters.fileUrl}}'
```

I am also attaching the Dockerfile for the image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CLI_ReadData/CLI_ReadData.csproj", "CLI_ReadData/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CLI_ReadData/CLI_ReadData.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CLI_ReadData"
RUN dotnet build "CLI_ReadData.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CLI_ReadData.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CLI_ReadData.dll"]
```

On running the workflow I receive the error code 145 along with the following logs:

> Could not execute because the application was not found or a
> compatible .NET SDK is not installed. Possible reasons for this
> include:
> * You intended to execute a .NET program:
> The application '/app/bin/Debug/net5.0/cli_readdata.dll' does not exist.
> * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
> It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
> Install a .NET SDK from:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

In the command section for `read-all-data` template I tried 2 approaches but both didn't work out.

**Approach 1 :** Providing the absolute url of the `CLI.ReadData.dll` file

```
command:
  - dotnet
  - /app/bin/Debug/net5.0/cli_readdata.dll
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
command:
  - dotnet
  - cli_readdata.dll
```

In both the conditions I am receiving the error. However when I run the below mentioned command within the docker container, it is working as expected, generating all the expected results.

```
dotnet /app/bin/Debug/net5.0/cli_readdata.dll --fileUrl="https://dpaste.com/24593EK38.txt"
```

So I just want to know, why isn't it working when running in a workflow ? Am I doing something wrong while passing the parameters, is there any error in the commands or anything needs to be changed with the Dockerfile ?